# Clearing special permissions from folders in a branch

Tags: version-control, permissions, branch

We're a fairly large project with a single trunk branch. Most of it uses the default permissions,  but a few folders have custom permissions - say, only "Builders" group is allowed to check-in.

We want to allow people to create their own private branches out of trunk, where they can freely check-in and merge later (hopefully often). However, creating a branch, the special permissions are copied along with the folders, meaning that people can't freely check-in into their branch.

- Is there a way to clear special permissions from a branch, or a folder?
- Is there a way to do so automatically, so anyone creating a branch under /private/** will not encounter this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out about [tf permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd05ft.aspx) (Example: `tf permission /inherit:yes itemSpec`). However, the /recursive switch doesn't work with it. I guess I could write something that runs it recursively...

*Edit:* I finally got around to writing a tool for it:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0 || args.Any(a => !a.StartsWith("$/")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Removes all explicit permissions and enables inheritance for a subtree.\n"
                        + "Example:  " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + " $/project/path1 $/project/path2");
        return 3;
    }

    WorkspaceInfo wi = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    if (wi == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't determine workspace for current directory: " + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        return 2;
    }

    var Tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(wi.ServerUri);
    VersionControlServer VersionControlServer = Tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}  Getting permissions...", wi.ServerUri);
    ItemSecurity[] perms = VersionControlServer.GetPermissions(args, RecursionType.Full);

    Console.WriteLine("Will remove explicit permissions from the following items:");

    var changes = new List<SecurityChange>();
    foreach (ItemSecurity perm in perms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + perm.ServerItem);

        changes.Add(new InheritanceChange(perm.ServerItem, inherit: true));
        foreach (AccessEntry e in perm.Entries)
        {
            changes.Add(new PermissionChange(perm.ServerItem, e.IdentityName, null, null, PermissionChange.AllItemPermissions));
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter to confirm:");
    Console.ReadLine();

    var successfulchanges = VersionControlServer.SetPermissions(changes.ToArray());
    if (successfulchanges.Length == changes.Count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit permissions removed from all items");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit permissions removed only from:");
        foreach (var c in successfulchanges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    " + c.Item);
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've just spent an hour trying to delete a branch because of some silly explicit permission. This cod fixed it in 2 seconds :)

Comment: Where do you execute this code? Can you tell how you use it? I am stuck with what I believe is a similar thing with some folder's permission preventing me from deleting or renaming a branch.

Comment: @mats-isaksson create a new console application

Comment: @Jonathan: thanks for the nice solution, you have definitely saved my day:)