# Delete TFS 2010 folder: Access Denied

Tags: tfs

My user is project administrator but when trying to check-in deletion of a folder getting "TF14098: Access Denied: User xxx needs Checkin permission(s) for $/.../folder/*.". Before deleting I needed to map, get & the check-in. Can't I just delete without get? Why am I getting above error?

Thanks.

EDIT: traced the problem to a single file that can't be deleted. File permissions show Allow for all permissions, for project administrator, but nevertheless when checking in the deletion getting error above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a full up to date local workspace to be able to delete. You should get latest at least to the scope of the delete.

Comment: Traced the problem to a single file that can't be deleted. File permissions show Allow for all permissions, for project administrator, but nevertheless when checking in the deletion getting error above.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, you have some files with weird permissions - probably one with "Deny" (which would supersede any Allows, even for admins).

If this happens a lot, see my Q&A [Clearing special permissions from folders in a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466972/clearing-special-permissions-from-folders-in-a-branch).

Comment: Thanks, but the file is marked as "allow" not "deny".

Answer (score 0):

If you're deleting a folder in Source Control Explorer that had branches inside it or other sub-folders that were deleted at some point in the past, the permissions on those deleted folders may prevent you from being able to delete.

In my case there were multiple branches that were first locked by applying deny permissions for check in, then deleted. Eventually when the root folder needed to be deleted this error appeared.

The fix was to click the "show/hide" deleted items, and remove the Deny permissions on all the deleted folders (Advanced->Security). Then VS let me delete the root folder.