# TFS 2012 set Inheritance On recursively

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, tfs

Our **Team Project** permissions was previously managed in **cluttery manner**. 
Permission are directly given to specific files / sub folders.

Am trying to **centralise all the permissions** now. So i need to remove all the (explicit) specific permissions and make everything inherit from the parent folder. Please see the image below.

[image: click here]

I have also searched for tfs command line but found no answers!

Is there quick way to do that? (with the TFS web access, c#, tf command line)

Comment: check this [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6651cf94-241b-4dd9-b9be-fee031bf7ab6/tfs-2012-remove-windows-user-tfs-group-from-team-project-branch-folder?forum=tfsadmin)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i need remove all the explicit  permission recursively. the above link doesn't have any recursive code.. Thanks for your effort

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466972/clearing-special-permissions-from-folders-in-a-branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600473/2074346
>
> and also to [SoftwareCarpenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054020/softwarecarpenter) for giving me reference.

I found out about [tf permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd05ft.aspx) (Example: `tf permission /inherit:yes itemSpec`). However, the /recursive switch doesn't work with it. I guess I could write something that runs it recursively...

*Edit:* I finally got around to writing a tool for it:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0 || args.Any(a => !a.StartsWith("$/")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Removes all explicit permissions and enables inheritance for a subtree.\n"
                        + "Example:  " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + " $/project/path1 $/project/path2");
        return 3;
    }

    WorkspaceInfo wi = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    if (wi == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't determine workspace for current directory: " + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        return 2;
    }

    var Tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(wi.ServerUri);
    VersionControlServer VersionControlServer = Tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}  Getting permissions...", wi.ServerUri);
    ItemSecurity[] perms = VersionControlServer.GetPermissions(args, RecursionType.Full);

    Console.WriteLine("Will remove explicit permissions from the following items:");

    var changes = new List<SecurityChange>();
    foreach (ItemSecurity perm in perms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + perm.ServerItem);

        changes.Add(new InheritanceChange(perm.ServerItem, inherit: true));
        foreach (AccessEntry e in perm.Entries)
        {
            changes.Add(new PermissionChange(perm.ServerItem, e.IdentityName, null, null, PermissionChange.AllItemPermissions));
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter to confirm:");
    Console.ReadLine();

    var successfulchanges = VersionControlServer.SetPermissions(changes.ToArray());
    if (successfulchanges.Length == changes.Count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit permissions removed from all items");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit permissions removed only from:");
        foreach (var c in successfulchanges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    " + c.Item);
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The tf command can revoke the permissions:

[tf command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd05ft(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: tf permission /remove:* /group:developers $/baseobjects

Answer (score 0):

You can set these permissions in Team Foundation Server by right-clicking the server in Team Explorer, and then clicking Security. You can set these permissions by using the TFSSecurity command-line utility, except for those command-line utilities with a tf: designation. For those with the tf: designation, use the Permission command of the tf command-line utility for source control to set the permissions.

For More Reference [TFSSecurity Command-Line Utility Commands and Permission Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.90).aspx)