# How to Toggle Inheritance for Area in TFS Using API?

Tags: c#, tfs

Creating a console application for the automation of area production within TFS, as our team produces more projects. One of the things that we still have to manually do once the application creates the area is to toggle the inheritance of the area to *Off*, as it is *On* by default. Is there any way to do this using TFS' API in Visual Studios with C#?

This is how I create the area:

```
static void CreateArea()
{
    string collectionUri = "collectionUri";
    string projectName = "projectName";
    string areaName = "areaName";
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUri));        
    ICommonStructureService commonStructures = tpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();

    // Root area of the project
    NodeInfo rootAreaNode = commonStructures.GetNodeFromPath(projectName + "\\Area");

    // Create the new area node
    string newAreaUri = commonStructures.CreateNode(areaName, rootAreaNode.Uri);

    Console.WriteLine("Created Area: '" + areaName + "'.");
}
```

Comment: What's the `inheritance `  are you point to? Did you mean the  inheritance permission related  for  the **security**  of newly created area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the inheritance and want to change the default **on** to **off**

[image]

You could use tf permission command to revoke the permissions. Sample Code as below:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0 || args.Any(a => !a.StartsWith("$/")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Removes all explicit permissions and enables inheritance for a subtree.\n"
                        + "Example:  " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + " $/project/path1 $/project/path2");
        return 3;
    }

    WorkspaceInfo wi = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    if (wi == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't determine workspace for current directory: " + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        return 2;
    }

    var Tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(wi.ServerUri);
    VersionControlServer VersionControlServer = Tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}  Getting permissions...", wi.ServerUri);
    ItemSecurity[] perms = VersionControlServer.GetPermissions(args, RecursionType.Full);

    Console.WriteLine("Will remove explicit permissions from the following items:");

    var changes = new List<SecurityChange>();
    foreach (ItemSecurity perm in perms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + perm.ServerItem);

        changes.Add(new InheritanceChange(perm.ServerItem, inherit: true));
        foreach (AccessEntry e in perm.Entries)
        {
            changes.Add(new PermissionChange(perm.ServerItem, e.IdentityName, null, null, PermissionChange.AllItemPermissions));
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter to confirm:");
    Console.ReadLine();

    var successfulchanges = VersionControlServer.SetPermissions(changes.ToArray());
    if (successfulchanges.Length == changes.Count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit permissions removed from all items");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit permissions removed only from:");
        foreach (var c in successfulchanges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    " + c.Item);
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

More details please refer this question: [Clearing special permissions from folders in a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466972/clearing-special-permissions-from-folders-in-a-branch/10600473#10600473)

Comment: This will remove any inherited permissions, but the inheritance drop-down menu still has _On_ checked off. That is as good as we can do, correct?

Comment: @JoshEvans Yes, there is no way to directly change the UI on web portal.  This will got the same result as you manually turn the inheritance to off. Just like a  workaround.